# Fortran to C , effect of trim on space allocated to string

Tags: c, fortran

I have a Fortran subroutine that calls a C function. One of the arguments to the C function is a fortran string. This is initialized as an empty string of length 512 bytes, and is passed to the C function as `trim(str)//char(0)` , i.e. it is trimmed and a `\0` is appended so that C sees its `strlen` as 0.

```
character(len=512)  :: str = ""
call C_foo (  trim(str)//char(0)  )
```

Now inside the C function, 
can I do this

```
strncpy (str, "something", strlen("something") )
```

What I want to know is that since `trim` is a transformational function as mentioned in its [docs](http://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gfortran/TRIM.html) , does passing it to C actually alter the space allocated to it? Inside the C function, will a strncpy ever fail (as far as length of source string < 512) ? I tried it and it works fine, but I want to be sure it is safe.

Comment: trim returns a zero length string in this case, so no it is not safe at all. More likely what you want to do is not use trim at all but set str(1:1)=char(0) ..

Comment: @george could you post your comment as an answer?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

elaborating on my comment, without getting into what "C" does, consider this pure fortran example:

```
character(len=512) :: g=""
call f(trim(g))
end

subroutine f(s)
character(len=*) :: s
integer :: i
do i=1,100
 s(i:i)="0"
enddo
end
```

This compiles fine but seg faults, while just

```
call f(g)
```

is just fine. Alternately if we assign g to be a sufficiently long nonblank string, eg add

```
g(100:100)="0"
```

it works a well.

what you see is the string passed by trim() has only the required lenght (which is zero in the first case), or 1 if you add //char(0) )

Incidentally a simple assignment in the subroutine

```
s=" ... 512 characters .. "
```

works..assiging only however many character will fit in the supplied space.
Interesting that (gfortran) somehow knows how much space to fill.. but I wouldnt count on it.

Comment: Separate to the length of the result of trim, note that `trim(g)` is an expression, the result of which here is a value, not a variable.  It is not conforming for a procedure to try and define a dummy argument that is associated with a value.  Beyond that - a procedure with a character(*) dummy argument knows the length of the actual argument (usually it is passed as a hidden argument) - hence the last assignment "works".

Comment: well my long winded point was to say "don't do it"..it is a curious thing how that string length is known by the subroutine. Going back tho the "C" question there seems to be no way for the C routine to access that information.

Answer (score 4):

Why not `use` the ISO_C_BINDING and initialize the string via:

```
character(len=512)  :: str = C_NULL_CHAR
```

Then the string will be be 512 long, with the first character being the C string null character and the remainder blanks.

Comment: I see. Thats a possible solution. But without the ISO_C_BINDING, will it work? I am curious to know how the space allocation works.

Comment: You could do `str = char(0)` without the ISO_C_BINDING.   Standard Fortran strings are fixed length.  If the RHS side is shorter than the string in an assignment statement, the string is padded with trailing spaces.