# Passing string between Fortran and C

Tags: c, fortran

I have a problem with passing strings between Fortran and C.

The Fortran subroutine call looks like this:

```
CALL MMEINITWRAPPER(TRIM(ADJUSTL(PRMTOP)), 0, SALTCON, RGBMAX, CUT)
```

The C which works with this has the signature:

```
int mmeinitwrapper_(char *name,
                    int *igb,
                    REAL_T *saltcon,
                    REAL_T *rgbmax1,
                    REAL_T *cutoff1)
```

I put some print statements in various places and everything works just fine, until I compile with ifort. In that case, the output looks like this:

```
  Topology file name:
 coords.prmtop                                                                  
   coords.prmtop
 Topology file name length:          81          13
length in C: 8 
read argument: coords.prmtop��* 
Reading parm file (coords.prmtop��*)
coords.prmtop��*, coords.prmtop��*.Z: does not exist
Cannot read parm file coords.prmtop��*
```

With the Portland compiler:

```
  Topology file name:
 coords.prmtop                                                                    
 coords.prmtop
 Topology file name length:           81           13
length in C: 8 
read argument: coords.prmtop 
Reading parm file (coords.prmtop)
```

The lengths in the first set are from Fortran of the untrimmed/unadjusted string and then the trimmed/adjusted string. The length in C is from `sizeof(name)/sizeof(name[0])`.

It seems to be passing a section of memory that's too long and in subsequent runs you get different lengths of bad stuff written (though the reported length in C is always 8).

Does anyone have any ideas? It's difficult getting gdb to play nicely with the Fortran/C combination.

Comment: I don't understand if you are calling fortran code from c code or vice versa? In other words, where is the "*name" string allocated and set before passing to a function (the c interface or the fortran code?)

Comment: Sorry, `*name` is allocated in the Fortran code, which calls the C code.

Comment: What happens if you `CALL MMEINITWRAPPER(TRIM(ADJUSTL(PRMTOP))//c_null_char,...)`, where `c_null_char` is a constant from `use iso_c_binding, only: c_null_char`?

Comment: What code do you have control over? In C, you would expect a "0" character ("\0") at the end of the string to mark the end of word. It seems that the various fortran compiler treats the TRIMM-ed string differently leaving zeros or not in some cases. Could you add the number of characters in the prototype to have the C code strncpy the first characters?

Comment: There is no reason, why Fortran code should add zeroes to strings.It always have to be appended manually.

Comment: In this era it is easier to communicate between Fortran and C using the Fortran ISO_C_Binding instead of deducing the passing mechanisms of a particular pair of compilers.  Additionally a solution based on the ISO_C_Binding will be portable.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I believe the answer you're looking for is here:

[Arrays of strings in fortran-C bridges using iso_c_binding](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9686532/arrays-of-strings-in-fortran-c-bridges-using-iso-c-binding)

Basically, fortran "knows" the length of a string but not C so you have to let the C code know somehow by transmitting the fortran length to C and then reacting appropriately in the C code.

This question below explore this issue from a "pure" fortran POV with some insights in the various answers given:

[Fortran to C , effect of trim on space allocated to string](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19032980/fortran-to-c-effect-of-trim-on-space-allocated-to-string)

And bear in mind that the compilers might exploit some undefined or implementation-specific differences to explain the varied observed behavior.

Also, I just realized you make a mistake by assuming that `sizeof` gives the size of the string. It gives the size of the pointer. So `sizeof(name)/sizeof(name[0])` is a constant giving the size of a `char` which itself is a constant of 8 bytes in C. `sizeof(name)` gives the size of a char pointer and `sizeof(name[0])` gives the size of a char. The result is a constant 8.

Comment: Also see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8207997/calling-a-fortran-subroutine-from-c/8208960

Comment: and http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9972743/creating-a-fortran-interface-to-a-c-function-that-returns-a-char

Answer (score 2):

There are several problems here.

- `sizeof(name)` in C returns the size of the pointer called name.  I take it you are on a 64 bit platform - hence you always see 8.
- C often expects string length to be determined by a trailing null sentinel character.  The absence of that character can produce strange results.  We can't be sure whether that is an issue here without more information.
- Fortran compilers differ in their passing conventions for the length of a character variable - it may be as an additional thing immediately after a pointer to the character data, or appended to the end of the other arguments.  The rules around interoperability of a procedure with the BIND(C) attribute remove the requirement to pass this length as interoperable character variables can only be of length one.  We can't be sure whether this is a problem as you don't show an interface block for the subroutine call on the Fortran side.

So... decide on how you are managing string length on the C side (fixed length?  terminating null?  separately passed length?), adjust the Fortran call appropriately and add an interface block to the Fortran side with BIND(C).